# Sorting a Drop-down (value) list by second field that's not displayed

Tags: filemaker

How can I have a drop-down (value) list sorted by a second field (`sortId`) **without showing** that field? (I also want to include a "separator line".)

My current solution uses a second field of whitespaces to sort, but this leads to unfortunate behaviour.

#### Problem:

As the list needs to be dynamic (i.e. read from a table) I cannot use a Custom Value List.
The list should look like this:

```
zzz (sortId = 1)
aaa (sortId = 2)
bbb (sortId = 3)
-------------------     (Does maybe also have to be defined with a sortId..)
uuu (sortId = 4)
lll (sortId = 5)
rrr (sortId = 6)
```

But the `sortId` should not be displayed in the drop-down list.

#### What I tried:

Since drop-down lists get sorted alphabetically I found out that there is [this trick](http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/cbe27249a0) with using a second field which
contains "whitespaces" as sorting order. With a script/command:

```
Substitute(10^sortId - 1, "9", " ")
```

I am able to convert `sortId` into the correct amount of whitespaces. The sorting then works...

**However**, whitespaces are still shown in the Drop-down list and because we have maybe around 100 items in the value list it expands the drop-down to the right.

Another problem is that we need to use the "-" as separator line, but with this approach the "-" does not get replaced by the separator line, because the blank whitespaces are still filled behind it so its "-     " and this
does not get replaced by the separator line.

Comment: It's ridiculous that this behaviour is not available in Filemaker by default... there *must* be a nicer way than using whitespace. :(

Comment: Yes it is.. It is really frustrating. Specially as a Java/Objective-C Programmer knowing how easy it would be to implement that :).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this technique is similar to what you've already tried, only it uses a 0-width Byte Order Mark, Char 65279:

http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2012/09/extending-filemaker-pro%E2%80%99s-value-list-sort-capabilities-using-char-function

It won't give you functionality for the separator line, but you should be able to get a sortable list this way.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the solution. This is kind of smarter than the spaces solution. But still there is the limit of 100 entries which we maybe gonna exceed :(. But thank you!

Comment: does this require Filemaker Advanced?

Comment: If you use the Custom Functions you would need FileMaker Advanced. If you look in Nil's comments of the article there's a way to do it without recursion --Substitute( 10^ n-1; 9; s )-- so you should be able to do the same thing without Advanced.